# Is this property of quotient maps true?

Tags: general-topology

I want to show:

> Let $f:X \to Z$ be a quotient map. Then $Z$ is Hausdorff if and only if whenever $x,y\in X$ and $f(x)\ne f(y)$, then there are $U,V$ neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$ respectively such that $U,V$ are disjoint and saturated with respect to $f$, i.e. $U=f^{-1}(f(U))$ and the same for $V$.

I have a problem with the implication $\Leftarrow$

**Here is my argument:**

I want to show that $Z$ is Hausdorff. Let $z\ne t\in Z$. Since $f$ is surjective, we have $t=f(x)$ and $z=f(y)$, and by hypothesis then there are $U,V$ neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$ respectively such that $U,V$ are disjoint and saturated with respect to $f$. Then we have $U=f^{-1}(U')$ and $V=f^{-1}(V')$ for some $U',V'$ subsets of $Y$. Is easily follows that $U'$ and $V'$ are disjoint and $t \in U'$ and $z \in V'$.

**Problem** how do I show that $U'$ and $V'$ are neighborhoods of $t$ and $z$ respectively?

For example, I have that there is an open set $A$ of $X$ with $x\in A \subseteq U$, but I don't know if $f(A)$ is open or not in $Y$. So how do I find an open subset of $Y$ wich is contained in $U'$ and contains $t$?

**Warning**: The definition of neighborhood we use here is : $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in $X$ if there is an open subset $A$ of $X$ such that $x \in A \subseteq U$. So here $U$ need not to be open. (See the comments to the answers below)

**Since** quotient maps transform saturated open subsets of the domain in open subsets of the codomain, I should find a saturated open subset $A\subseteq X$  such that $x\in A \subseteq U$. In this way $f(A)$ is open and $t\in f(A) \subseteq U'$. **Any idea on how to do this?**

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right then $U'=f(U)$. As you wrote you know that $f(U)$ contains the point $t$. Now why is it open? $f$ is a quotient map, so $f(U)$ is open in $Z$ if and only if its inverse image is open in $X$. But you know that $U=f^{-1}(f(U))$ and $U$ is an open set in $X$. Hence $U'=f(U)$ is open in $Z$, so it is a neighborhood of the point $t$. Now do the same thing for $V'$.

Comment: $U$ is **not** an open neighborhood of $x$, just a neighborhood of $x$. So I only know that $U$ contains a subset $A$ wich is open in $X$ and $x \in A$

Comment: Are you sure? From what I know the definition of a neighborhood is "an open set which contains the point". Maybe there are different definitions as well, but I always thought of a neighborhood as an open set. Oh, you are right, I heard that some define it like you described.

Comment: Yes, some books consider neighborhoods to be open sets, while others consider neighborhoods in the more general setting of "a set cointaing an open set containinf the point"

Comment: For example $[0,1]$ is a neighborhood of $1/2$ because $1/2 \in (0,1)\subseteq [0,1]$ and $(0,1)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Yes, you are right. I heard about that definition, though I never used it. Need to think about the problem more then.

Answer (score 1):

Following your notation, we have $t=f(x), z=f(y)$ and we have $U$ open in $X$ and containing $x$ such that $f^{-1}[f[U]] = U$ and also $V$ (disjoint from $U$) open in $X$ containing $y$  with $f^{-1}[f[V]] = V$.

It follows that $f[U]$ is open: $f$ is a quotient map, so by definition any set with open pre-image must be open, and $f[V]$ is open too for the same reason. As $f$ is surjective, and their pre-images are disjoint, $f[U]$ and $f[V]$ are also disjoint and are clearly the required disjoint neighbourhoods for $t$ and $z$.

Comment: In the book from which I took this exercise, the definition of a neighborhood is not that of a necessarily open set; so I don't know that $U$ is open in $X$ (See the discussion below the other answer)

Comment: @Minato It doesn't matter. $A$ is a neighbourhood of $y=f(x)$ iff $f^{-1}[A]$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, should be provable for quotient maps...

Comment: "$A$ is a neighbourhood of $y=f(x)$ iff $f^{-1}[A]$ is a neighbourhood of $x$"... this is precisely my problem. I'm not able to prove it

Comment: I have $f^{-1}(U')$ is a neighborhood of $x$ but I'm not able to prove that $U'$ is a neighborhood of $f(x)=t$

Comment: If you prove your statement "$A$ is a neighbourhood of $y=f(x)$ iff $f^{−1}[A]$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, should be provable for quotient maps" we are done

Comment: Or maybe the exercise is wrong and the map $f$ should also be open?

Comment: From what book is that exercise by the way?

Comment: @Mark it's an italian book. Can you read italian?

Comment: @Minato unfortunately not.

Comment: @Mark I assure you that I didn't make mistake on how to interpret the exercise. I'm beginning to think that we need also $ f$ to be open map. So can anyone provide a counterexample to my statement?